# WooCommerce checkout tabs

Tags: woocommerce

Can someone tell me how can I create tabs for the checkout page in woocommerce? For example, I need a type of billing for individual people and other tab and kind of billing for a legal person?

I put a pic so you can see (this is from a Romanian site, and i wish it looks like here)

[example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNDuY.png)

Comment: Please refrain from using unnecessary formatting that doesn't add value to the question.

Comment: i am bad at english and i dont understand all :( sorry

Comment: There is no need for empty blockquotes or the `<blink>` tags in your question.

Comment: it didn't let me to public the question without blockquote, and i didnt understood all the rules about how to post a question here

Comment: Well I think it didn't let you post it because it didn't fit the rules as defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially about a minimal example. You don't show any attempt / efforts at all, and StackOverflow is *not* a code writing service. We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. You are expected to try to write the code yourself.

Comment: thanks, i will read more about asking, before i will ask again